# ReSharper error when executing SonarQube analysis from TFS 2013 build

Tags: tfs, sonarqube, resharper, sonarqube5.1

I have been setting up SonarQube analysis from a TFS 2013 build using the instructions made by Microsoft ALM Rangers:
https://vsarguidance.codeplex.com/downloads/get/1452516

It all Works fine, until I add ReSharper analysis, then i get an error;

> 09:51:49: ERROR: Error during Sonar runner execution
>
> 09:51:49: ERROR: Unable to execute Sonar
>
> 09:51:49: ERROR: Caused by: The property "sonar.resharper.cs.reportPath" must be set.

I have added a sonar-project.properties file to TFS in the same directory as my solution file.

The file looks like:

> sonar.resharper.projectName=CommonComponents
> sonar.resharper.cs.reportPath=resharperresults.xml

Im using SonarQube 5.1 and the R# 2.0 plugin

Running analysis from Jenkins Works fine.

I really hope you can help me out of this. Im pretty sure its something stupid that I just can't turn my eyes around to see.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The support of the R# by the MSBuild Runner is only going to become available in the version 1.0 of the MSBuild Runner & 2.0 of the R#. See the following tickets:

- http://jira.sonarsource.com/browse/SONARMSBRU-16
- http://jira.sonarsource.com/browse/SONARRSHPR-15

Comment: Explains a lot. Went back to having Jenkins as the main build server. Everything is working now.